# No changes to app after redeployment to EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, visual-studio-2019

I've got development and production instances in EC2. I've been updating my app in Visual Studio 2019 and redeploying it to the dev instance, then creating an AMI of that instance and using that image to update the production instance(s).

Suddenly my app no longer updates when I deploy to the dev instance. The logs all show the update was applied, but when I look at the files on the server they have not changed for days. I suspect I may be using AMIs incorrectly, but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

How do I get my updates to show again?

Comment: Are you creating an AMI from a running instance in an environment and then adding it to another? That's not the right approach, here's from the aws docs:
Don't create an AMI from an instance that has been launched in an Elastic Beanstalk environment. Elastic Beanstalk makes changes to instances during provisioning that can cause issues in the saved AMI. Saving an image from an instance in an Elastic Beanstalk environment will also make the version of your application that was deployed to the instance a fixed part of the image.

Comment: Thanks @AliAbbas. That helps me figure out what's wrong... what's the proper way to go about things? The reason I am using an AMI is because I have custom software installed that needs to be on each instance (for instance, an email managing service).

Comment: I'm going to add that as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are facing the issue because creating an AMI from running environment isn't the right approach since EB runs several scripts under the hood to attach instances to that particular environment.

Note: Custom AMIs are ideal only when you're installing a lot of dependencies or software that you want to be baked into your AMI so subsequent deployments go through quick. Here's the [documentation that walks you through the steps](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.customenv.html#using-features.customenv.create), and here's the summary of the steps:

- The best approach would be to launch a stand alone EC2 using an EB
  AMI as base (ideally an AMI with HVM virtualization).
- Connect to the instance with SSH or RDP.
- Perform any customizations you want.
- (Windows platforms) Run the EC2Config service Sysprep. For
  information about EC2Config, see Configuring a Windows Instance Using
  the EC2Config Service. Ensure that Sysprep is configured to generate 
  a random password that can be retrieved from the AWS Management
  Console.
- In the Amazon EC2 console, stop the EC2 instance. Then on the
  Instance Actions menu, choose Create Image (EBS AMI).

Comment: Ok... this all makes sense and I was able to create an image successfully but have an additional problem. SSL support in IIS.

I have two environments: dev and prod. prod is behind a load balancer with an SSL cert. dev is just a single instance. Then I have my new base instance. How do I set up support for SSL so that when I use this AMI for my prod instances they use the appropriate certificate?

Comment: You can just add an SSL cert to the load balancer, AMI doesn't play any role in this as long as you want to terminate SSL on the ELB and don't want end to end encryption. You can open the env, go to configuration, open the load balancer and add a listener, choose 443 and the Cert (that you can create via ACM or upload). Here's more info:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/configuring-https-elb.html

Comment: I've done that part, but when I log into an instance, the IIS in the instance doesn't have the bindings set to accept https... only http. Is there something I have to do to enable the instance to have https support by default?

Comment: If you're terminating ssl on the ELB, traffic b/w ELB and instance will be unencrypted. If you want end to end encryption (which is comparatively uncommon) then you'll need to enable https on the instance also, here's how you can do on Amazon EC2 instances running .NET:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/SSLNET.SingleInstance.html